# Why is `find -name *.jks` not returning some files?

Tags: find, wildcards

```
find . -name *.jks -print 2>/dev/null
```

returns files of extension *jks* that do **not have underscores** as part of their name.  Much to my surprise, I have just discovered that * does NOT substitute the underscore.

```
find . -name *_*.jks -print 2>/dev/null
```

returns files of extension *jks* that **have one underscore**.

How do I search for files that have 0 or more underscores?  Using OSX Mountain Lion.

Comment: Is your `find` supporting _and_ logical operator? `find . -name '*.jks' -a ! -name '*_*.jks'`

Comment: `find . -name '*.jks' -print 2>/dev/null` worked.  you can submit an answer, @manatwork, and i will go ahead and accept it and up vote

Comment: Your question is a bit strange: in my Linux (CentOS 5), your sample doesn't work. I have to write "*.jks". And, anyway, it returns **all** files with extension jks, with or without an underscore, that is what you are asking for.

Comment: @AndrewQ, probably amphibient has no *.jks file in the work directory itself, so the wildcard is not expanded before the execution of `find`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

all versions of `find` that I know will match underscores with wildcards.

be warned that when doing.

```
find . -name *.jks -print 2>/dev/null
```

the "`*.jks`" might get expanded by the shell, before running the find command.

e.g.

```
$ mkdir foo
$ touch a.jks foo/a.jks foo/b.jks
a.jks
$ find . -name *.jks -print
./a.jks
./foo/a.jks
```

this is really because you are actually calling `find . -name a.jks -print`, and thus it will not find e.g. `b.jks`.

if you quote the wildcard expression, you might have more luck:

```
$ find . -name "*.jks" -print
./a.jks
./foo/a.jks
./foo/b.jks
```

i'm pretty sure that running

```
$ find . -name "*.jks" -print
```

will give you all files with and without underscores.